# creating large files with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello I have a question with node.js mainly with creating new larger files.

I understand how to do stuff such as

```
fs.writeFile('ss.js', 'console.log("hello")');
```

But my problem comes when I need to create a file that has 5 or more lines, AKA all the files. I'm not sure where to even start on this problem. I've been through a lot of tutorials and all of them jusy say, "Now create a file and fill it with these lines of code.", but none of them actually go indepth into how to create a file with multiple lines of code.

Greatly appreciated if anyone can go over this basic step. Thanks!

Comment: you can add newline character "\r\n" in your text to create multiline content. Look at appendFile method as well. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Answer (score 2):

You're kind of undermining "large files".  Those are simply line-breaks, which is (at least on Unix) around 5 extra bytes (since linebreaks are represented as a single byte).

Take this example:

```
fs.writeFile("test.js", "var test = 'ey b0ss';\nconsole.log(test);\nif (true) {\nconsole.log('yey');\n}");
```

In this example, line-breaks are represented as `\n`, considering you're on a Unix machine, this would work fine (If you're on a Windows machine, I think `\r` is the alternative)... (You can use the `\r\n` combo to represent a line-break on both OS's.)

The output of this on a Unix machine is:

```
var test = 'ey b0ss';
console.log(test);
if (true) {
console.log('yey');
}
```

---

When actually creating large files (in terms of storage), in my opinion, it'd be best to represent it as a buffer.

For instance, say we wanted to create a file that had 100,000 "a" characters in it.

```
var largeBuffer = new Buffer(""), i,
anotherBuffer = new Buffer("a"),
fs = require("fs");

for (i=0; i<=100000; i++) {
  largeBuffer = Buffer.concat([largeBuffer, anotherBuffer]);
}

fs.writeFile("a.txt", largeBuffer);
```